# null values inserted while auditing

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My AuditListener

```
public class EmployeeAuditListeners {
@PrePersist
public  void prePersist(Employee employee){
    perform(employee,Action.INSERTED);
}

@PreUpdate
public void preUpdate(Employee employee){
    perform(employee,Action.UPDATED);
}

@PreRemove
public void preRemove(Employee employee){
    perform(employee,Action.DELETED);
}

@Transactional
public void  perform(Employee emp, Action action){
    EntityManager em = BeanUtil.getBean(EntityManager.class);
    CommonLogs commonLogs = new CommonLogs();
    commonLogs.setQuery("new query");
    em.persist(commonLogs);
}
}
```

and My **Auditable.class**

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class Auditable<U> {

    @CreatedBy
    protected U createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    protected Date createdDate;

    @LastModifiedBy
    protected U lastModifiedBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    protected Date lastModifiedDate;
}
```

My **CommonLogs.class**

```
@Entity 
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)

public class CommonLogs extends Auditable<String> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;


    private  String query;


    public CommonLogs() {
    }

    public CommonLogs(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getQuery() {
        return query;
    }

    public void setQuery(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }
}
```

**My Employee.java class**

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(EmployeeAuditListeners.class)
public class Employee {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String address;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

and I have a simple Rest Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class EmployeeController {


    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @PostMapping("/employees")
    public Employee createEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee){
        return employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }
}
```

I want to log it on my table (common_logs) every time i perform some crud operations on my Employee Entity.

the above given example is working to some extent as it successfully stores employee and invokes EmployeeAuditListeners.

but now while saving CommongLog entity i expect it's parent class Auditable to automatically insert createdBy, createdDate etc. for now only query and id is inserted on common_logs table and remaining columns are null.

Answer (score 0):

You can review the documentation for Auditing in [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.0.DATAJPA-580-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/auditing.html).

To enable the automatic Auditing, you must add the annotation `@EnableJpaAuditing` in your Application class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaAuditing
class Application {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args)
    }
}
```

If you want the fields `@CreatedBy` and `@LastModifiedBy` too, you will also need to implement the `AuditorAware<T>` interface. For example:

```java
class SpringSecurityAuditorAware implements AuditorAware<User> {

  public User getCurrentAuditor() {

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    if (authentication == null || !authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
      return null;
    }

    return ((MyUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUser();
  }
}
```